# Errors at std::count (no conversion error)

Tags: c++, count

Trying to resolve an error resulting from use of the std::count function.  I've gone through the template in xutility and it appears that the types match, so I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors.  I'm using the count function in two instances and they're throwing two different errors.

The first error is:

```
C2446 '==': no conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'int'
```

Here's the code that creates this error (it's the beginnings of a comparator for sorting):

```
struct vectorComparator
{
    bool operator ()(const string& string1, const string& string2)
    {
        if (count(string1.begin(), string1.end(), "!") < count(string2.begin(), string2.end(), "!") + 1)
            return string1 < string2;
        return string1 < string2;
    }
};
```

The second error is very similar:

```
C2446 '==': no conversion from 'const _Ty' to 'int'
```

Here's the code that creates this error:

```
string myClass::myFunction(string parentToken)
{
    string messageChunk{};
    vector<string> tokens;

    for (auto it = messageMap.begin(); it != messageMap.end(); ++it)
        if (it->first.find(parentToken) != string::npos && 
            count(it->first.begin(), it->first.end(), elementDelimiter) == count(parentToken.begin(), parentToken.end(), elementDelimiter) + 1)
        {
            tokens = explode(elementDelimiter, it->first);
            messageChunk += (messageChunk.size() > 0 ? "," : "") + '\"' + tokens[tokens.size()] + "\":" + buildValueString(it->second);
            messageMap.erase(it);
        }

    messageChunk = '{' + messageChunk + '}';

    if (arrayTokens.find(tokens[tokens.size() - 1]) != string::npos)
        messageChunk += '\"' + tokens[tokens.size() - 1] + "\":[" + messageChunk + ']';
    else messageChunk += '\"' + tokens[tokens.size() - 1] + "\":" + messageChunk;

    return messageChunk;
}
```

With the understanding that I'm new to this and I'm sure there's plenty of ways to streamline the code (and I'll take all input), I'm primarily looking for help with resolving the two errors.  It seems to be a type issue, but I can't resolve it.  In the second sample elementDelimiter is defined as const char* and is equal to "!".  Thanks for any help or guidance you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:
1 case: string consist of char. And "count" tries to compare string ("!") with int-like-char. It can't. You can use '!' instead of "!" (single quotes define single char).

2 case: I think it has the same error (What is the messageMap type?).

In second case you can use 'count' with predicate:

```
count(it->first.begin(), it->first.end(), [elementDelimiter](char symbol){
  // Here you should define your comparison operation. Like this:
  return elementDelimiter[0] == symbol; })
```

Comment: Awesome, that completely resolved the first problem and I'm an idiot for not seeing that.  I've already resolved several issues with single character strings being in single vs. double quotes.  Thanks for pointing it out!  It did not, however, resolve the second issue.  I guess the bigger question is, if elementDelimiter is a class private const char* = "!", how do I use it in the second example above?  I tried changing the type to std::string with no luck.  Also tried const char* = '!' and it didn't like that at all.

Comment: What is the type (or definition) of messageMap? Of elementDelimiter?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the second comment.  messageMap is an unordered_map<std::string,std::string>.

Comment: Sorry for my high-density today.  I'm getting another error when attempting to use the lambda function: E1738 the enclosing-function 'this' cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list.

Does 'symbol' need to be defined somwhere or is it just for use within the predicate?  Also, the above error is referring to the use of the class private elementDelimiter in the predicate.

Comment: If `elementDelimiter` is `const char*`, then it is the same problem as the first case. `const char elementDelimiter = '!';` would be the appropriate definition.

Comment: That was the problem with the second.  Thanks for the help.  It created a few other issues with arguments being passed to other functions, but I'll attempt to resolve those before bothering you guys again.  Thanks!